# Navigation Bar Div is Covering Another Div

Tags: html, css

I am working on a webpage. I made a top navigation bar, I put links in and more! Now I am trying to add a settings button. The button works, however when I position it, it stop working. I think it is because of the padding, I don't know how to fix it though. [The Padding Covers The Setting Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQVyH.png) [Code1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDK4r.png)

```css
/*Navigation Bar Below*/

nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #aeaeae;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #8d8d8d;
}

#list1{

}

#list1 li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 50px;
}

#list1 li a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: MPLUS;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

#list1 li a:hover{
    color: dodgerblue; 
}

.inputWithIcon {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 37px;
}

/*Channel ID Search Below*/

input[type=text]{
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: .3s;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  border-color: dodgerblue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 dodgerblue;
}

 input[type=text]{
    width:100%;
    border:2px solid #aaa;
    border-radius:4px;
    margin:8px 0;
    outline:none;
    padding: 8px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    transition:.3s;
  }
  
  input[type=text]:focus{
    border-color:dodgerBlue;
    box-shadow:0 0 8px 0 dodgerBlue;
  }
  
  .inputWithIcon input[type=text]{
    padding-right: 30px;
  }
  
  .inputWithIcon{
    position:relative;
  }
  
  .inputWithIcon i{
    position:absolute;
    right: 34.5px;
    top:8px;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    color:#aaa;
    transition:.3s;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .inputWithIcon input[type=text]:focus + i{
    color:dodgerBlue;
  }

 .search1{
     padding-right: 37px;
 }
 
/* Menu Button Below*/

.box-shadow-menu {
  position: absolute;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.box-shadow-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0.25em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 0.15em;
  background: black;
  box-shadow: 
    0 0.25em 0 0 black,
    0 0.5em 0 0 black;
}

.SettingsButton1{
    position:absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top:8px;
    padding: 9px 10px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="NavBar">
   <nav>
    <div class="SettingsButton1">
     <i class="box-shadow-menu" aria-hidden="true" id="button" onclick="ViewsDisplay1()"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="Search1">
     <div class="inputWithIcon">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Channel ID" id="chnlname">
      <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true" id="update"></i>
     </div>
    </div>
             <ul id="list1">
                 <li><a href="#">Liker</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html">Live Count</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Logan IS Dumb</a></li>
             </ul>
       </nav>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please provide your code, such as HTML and CSS

Comment: I added my code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you have a screenshot of what you want it to look like?

Comment: @Si8 I would like it to look how I have it currently. I need to fix the padding so the I can click the button.

Comment: Oh you mean the hamburger menu?

Comment: @Si8 Yes, The hamburger menu is my button, I used an <i> tag. I have already tested it and it works.

Comment: What does `ViewsDisplay1()` do?

Comment: @git-e-up It is Javascript Function, as I did not use a normal button I had to make it clickable. `function ViewsDisplay1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("ViewCountDisplay");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the SettingsButton1 div to after Search1 div.
So instead of below code..

```
<div class="SettingsButton1">
    <i class="box-shadow-menu" aria-hidden="true" id="button" onclick="ViewsDisplay1()"></i>
</div>
<div class="Search1">
    <div class="inputWithIcon">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Channel ID" id="chnlname">
        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true" id="update"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Use below code.

```
<div class="Search1">
    <div class="inputWithIcon">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Channel ID" id="chnlname">
        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true" id="update"></i>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="SettingsButton1">
    <i class="box-shadow-menu" aria-hidden="true" id="button" onclick="ViewsDisplay1()"></i>
</div>
```

or you can add z-index: 1 to SettingsButton1 class style.

**Update 1: CSS Solution**
Or if you want to do it with CSS only then add

```
.Search1{
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 37px;
}
```

and remove the `padding-right:37px` from .inputWithIcon class style..

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As a fix, could increment the z-index to the button in simple CSS to bring it to the front. However, you could provide your code so we can see exactly what are you talking about.

```
button {
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. I probably did something wrong though. `.SettingsButton1{
    position:absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top:8px;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    z-index: 999;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into the [Z-index property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) in CSS.

This allows you to define the stack order of elements in your HTML the higher the z-index value is the higher it will be rendered. so if you have the Div set to z index 1000 and the navbar to 500 the Div will render above the navbar. However you do need to check in debugger to see if it's being given a Z-Index already if you're using a component library like Bootstrap or Angular Material some things alread have Z-Indexes.